# How to insert a widget into created block factory block programmatically?

Tags: magento2

I've created a widget and a CMS block by using blockFactory class, like:

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $cmsBlockData = [
        'title' => 'Title',
        'identifier' => 'CMS block identifier',
        'content' => "CMS block content",
        'is_active' => 1,
        'stores' => [0],
        'sort_order' => 0
    ];
}
```

But this CMS block has to contain my created widget. I guess I need to specify that widget in my block, but not sure where. Could someone help me with that?

Besides that, what is the purpose of `'stores' => [0]` setting?